# WKWebView doesn't open @click listeners with redirect from Vue.js of icons <i>

Tags: ios, swift

Why doesn't WKWebView give any feedback for icon  links that has attached onClick listener by Vue?

I've had similar issue with navigation link but opening link in Safari fixed that but that doesn't work for those icon links (examples below).

```swift
    // this functions detects only the blog link but not the social icon links
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated  {
            if let url = navigationAction.request.url, UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                decisionHandler(.cancel)
            }
        }
    }
```

These social icons doesn't work, they work in Chrome (mobile simulator), they work in Safari on iPhone but not in iOS app that includes WKWebView. Is there some kind of protection for link going away from the hosting server?

[image: social]

This link does work

[image: blog]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have switched from `@click` and `window.open()` in Vue to `<a href=""><i></i></a>` and everything works well but this method still needs to be used in Xcode project:

```swift
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated  {
            if let url = navigationAction.request.url, UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                decisionHandler(.cancel)
            }
        }
    }
```